# Customize iOS Vision text-detection for other objects and typefaces

Tags: ios, machine-learning, apple-vision

I'm looking around for different solutions to a problem I'm having and right now I'm looking into the iOS Vision api.

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the text/feature detection methods provided by Vision for custom objects in an image, or custom typefaces?

Comment: Have you come to an answer yet? I would also like to detect custom glyphs with Vision Framework, not just alphabet/kanji/etc.

Comment: I used TuriCreate to train my own image classifier instead. Worked fine for my purpose, although may not always.

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm currently doing too; Turi Create trained model in CoreML. Just thought it would make a much cleaner solution to have Vision detect glyphs and then CoreML decipher them instead.